# Create and maintain a SignalR connection in a WinRT Background Task

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, signalr.client, background-task

I currently have a Windows Phone app that connects to a SignalR service to receive notification data. The service pushes data to the phone, which the app accepts, process etc and it’s all working as expected.

However, I would like the app to continue to receive the notification data when the app is suspended and no longer in the foreground, and display the notification data as a toast message.
From what I can see, the Background Task infrastructure offers no way to do this.
I have access to a Suspending and Resuming event (using Prism) so here I could Register/Unregister my background task.

For the trigger, the only one that comes close to being relevant is the TimeTrigger, but this only has a freshness time of 15 minutes, so assuming I am recreating the connection in the background task,  I would end up opening and then instantly closing the connection every 15 minutes which isn't what I want to do.

I could have an “infinite await” that just hangs until a timeout, but this doesn't feel like the right way to go (and the resource usage would be terrible).

Is there a way around this to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Windows Phone apps cannot keep a channel open like this. If the goal is only for toasts then you can do the computation on the server and push a toast notification.

Windows Store apps can do this with the [ControlChannelTrigger class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.controlchanneltrigger.aspx), but it is not supported on Windows Phone.